# Understanding combinational feedback loops

Tags: verilog, asic, vlsi, system-verilog

1. Please give me a simple example of a verilog code that results in combo feedback loop.
2. Why are these feedback loops undesired in your design? [How to interpret blocking vs non blocking assignments in Verilog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653284/how-to-interpret-blocking-vs-non-blocking-assignments-in-verilog) - StackOverflow question
3. Why/how are combo-loops present in (some) Finite State Machines and Pipeline stages?

Comment: Is this homework? What did you already try, and why don't you think it's correct? Exactly what language are you asking about (you used both Verilog and System Verilog tags)?

Comment: @ThePhoton : This is not a homework! I am new to this topic and the reason I thought it was incorrect is because, I read it in one of the responses on SO [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653284/how-to-interpret-blocking-vs-non-blocking-assignments-in-verilog).


I used both the tags because in my humble opinion there wont be much difference in the syntax that synthesizes to combo feedback loop using verilog or system verilog.

Answer (score 2):

Think about what is combinatorial logic?
Logic gates where the output is defined entirely by the input, there is no state.

Imagine b = XOR of a and b.

a changes to 1 output changes to 1 loops back xor is now 0, feedback means xor is now 1 etc.

This is an uncontrolled oscillation which will only stop when the input a is set 0 and it will stop in an undetermined state.

The example above should be able to code as: but any combinatorial logic which reuses an output is a loop.

```
input a;
reg b;

always @* begin
  b = b ^ a; 
end
```

or

```
input a;
wire b;
assign b = b ^ a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Combinatorial feedback loops are *usually* undesirable because the output will oscillate and the output is unpredictable. However, sometimes that's exactly what you want -- a hardware random number generator (RNG). Altera has released some example verilog code that does exactly that. See 14–2 in their [Advanced Synthesis Cookbook](http://www.altera.com/literature/manual/stx_cookbook.pdf).

Here's one of their examples, found [here, under random/ring_counter.v](http://www.altera.com/literature/manual/cookbook.zip):

```
module ring_counter (clk,rst,out);

parameter DELAY = 100;

input clk,rst;
output [15:0] out;

wire [DELAY-1:0] delay_line /* synthesis keep */;

reg [15:0] cntr;
reg sync0;
reg wobble;

// unstable ring oscillator
genvar i;
generate
for (i=1; i<DELAY; i=i+1)
  begin : del
    assign delay_line [i] = delay_line[i-1];
  end
endgenerate
assign delay_line [0] = !delay_line [DELAY-1];

// sync it over to the input clock
always @(posedge clk) begin
  sync0 <= delay_line[0];
  wobble <= sync0;
end

// count when the wobbly oscillator is high
always @(posedge clk or posedge rst) begin
  if (rst) cntr <= 0;
  else if (wobble) cntr <= cntr + 1;
end

assign out = cntr;

endmodule
```